# How to express "where value is in dynamic list" in HQL/GORM?

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

For a grails application, I need to find a list of objects whose "attr" is one in a dynamic list of strings. The actual HQL query is more complex, but the bit I need help with is this:

```
def result = MyObject.executeQuery("select o from MyObject as o where o.attr in :list",
    [list: aListOfStrings])
```

This is obviously not the right syntax, Grails throws it back at me as an "unexpected token", being the `:list` parameter.

Is this possible in HQL? I don't particularly want to use Criteria in this part of the codebase.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put :list in parens:

```
def result = MyObject.executeQuery(
    "select o from MyObject as o where o.attr in (:list)",
    [list: aListOfStrings])
```

Comment: I cant use this idea of  (:list) and [list : aList] with Sql.java class in grails

Comment: Burt 4 President!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how the performance compares, but I was able to do this straight in GORM with the `in` keyword in a `where` query:

```
def users = MyObject.where { attr in aListOfStrings }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me like champs.

Order.executeQuery("from Order o where o.categoryId = :ocatId  and o.part in (:partsList) and o.status in (:statusList)", [ocatId  : categoryId,  partsList:partsList, statusList:statusList] )